# how to change colors of my ps1 root terminal permanently

Tags: linux, debian, shell, terminal, colors

I want to change the colors of `root@MyComputer:~#`and when i type the ls command show me the result as colors!

I write a simple BB code to display what i want:

```
[color=red]root@MyComputer:[/color][color=blue]~[/color]#
```

I had this command but it does not apply whan open a new terminal window

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\$ '
```

thank you in advance

Comment: The questioner already knows how to change the colour (using hardwired control sequences, alas).  Xe is asking how to make the `PS1` setting _persistent_ in subsequent shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your command works, simply put it in `$HOME/.bashrc` if you are using a bash shell.

`$HOME` will be `/root` for root, `/home/XYZ` for user XYZ, etc.
For `ls` command, you can create an alias like so (again, in bashrc):

`alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

You can always source the `.bashrc` file too in your current shell if you, for some reason, do not want to spawn a new one.

Comment: thinks it work!